# Use Parallel.Foreach to update properties of entity with thread safety

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I am trying to leverage Parallel.Foreach to update properties of entity: Contact as shown in the code sample

```
var contactIds = new List<int>();
contactIds.AddRange(res.RelatedContacts.Select(c => c.IdVal).ToList());
contacts = await _dbContext.Contacts.Where(co => contactIds.Contains(co.ContactId)).ProjectTo<ContactDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

foreach (var contactrec in contacts)
{
    var contact = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContactId.Equals(contactrec.ContactId));
    if (contact != null)
    {
        contact.address = addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId.Equals(contact.AddressId));
        contact.ImagePath = contact.ImageId > 0 ? images.FirstOrDefault(im => im.ImageId.Equals(contact.ImageId)).FilePath : "NA";
    }
}
```

I want to replace the above code with Parallel.Foreach with thread safety.

Comment: What is `contacts`? Why do you want to parallelize this? Accessing common data and modifications *harm* parallelism.

Comment: What does this do in the first place? The code is already iterating over `contacts`, why is it trying to find other records in `Contacts` ? You can probably get **far** better performance by using the proper containers, eg Dictionaries for contacts, images and addresses, so there's no need to scan the entire container each time you want to find a match. Or you could use LINQ joins. LINQ/PLINQ's `join` operators will actually load one collection's data into a HashSet before joining.

Comment: Using the correct container could result in `Na*Ni` times better performance per loop, while parallelization can only offer **at best** a speed up equivalent to the number of cores.

Comment: Thanks much @PanagiotisKanavos for your response. I have updated the code now

Comment: What are you trying to do?? What is the actual problem? Parallelizing bad queries only makes them slower. In this case, it looks like you want to do an `UPDATE contacts FROM contacts inner join addresses inner join images`. Using an ORM to perform such queries only results in very slow execution. Parallelizing this results in *far worse* performance by increasing conflicts between connections

Comment: I am trying to update address and imagepath for each contact based on few other conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, there are some code smells there and probably writing the query in a more efficient way would speed up the whole process more than any optimization obtained with parallelism.

Having said this, I think that you're looking for something like this:

```
var contactIds = new List<int>();
contactIds.AddRange(res.RelatedContacts.Select(c => c.IdVal).ToList());
contacts = await _dbContext.Contacts.Where(co => contactIds.Contains(co.ContactId)).ProjectTo<ContactDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

Parallel.Foreach(contacts, contact => Update(contact));
//or: Parallel.Foreach(contacts, Update);
```

```
void Update(Contact contact){
    contact.address = addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId.Equals(contact.AddressId));
    contact.ImagePath = contact.ImageId > 0 ? images.FirstOrDefault(im => im.ImageId.Equals(contact.ImageId)).FilePath : "NA";
}
```

Some notes:

- no need to iterate through the Ids and then get the first element with that Id. Just iterate the elements.
- there shouldn't be any thread safe issue, the operations in `Update` are readonly.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. It helped me to fine tune my code better :)